# Why I can't access remote Jupyter Notebook server?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

After doing all the config, I still cannot access jupyter notebook from remote host.The jupyter log like this:
`[I 10:01:03.267 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from path/jupyterlab
[I 10:01:03.267 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is path/jupyter/lab
[I 10:01:03.273 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: path
[I 10:01:03.273 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:01:03.273 NotebookApp] http://(ip-inet addr or 127.0.0.1):8889/
[I 10:01:03.273 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).`
I want to get: 
`The Jupyter Notebook is running at:http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8889/`
Anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I get my answer.The server restrict access of external networks...I found it today.I'm speechless...